# É possível descobrir a duração de um áudio pela requisição do Express?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express.js

Olá, tudo certo?

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Node.js com Express que tem como uma de suas funções receber um arquivo de audio e armazenar no banco de dados as informações do arquivo. Estou passando esse arquivo em formato `.ogg` dentro da requisição, e no corpo da requisição estou passando a duração do audio manualmente. 
 
Existe alguma maneira de obter a duração do audio a partir da requisição? 
 
Segue um exemplo da minha função `post()`

```js
route.post(
  '/upload',
  upload.single('audio'),
  (request, response) => {
    const { title, description, tags, duration, post_time } = request.body;
    const createAudioSevice = new CreateAudioService();

    const audio = createAudioSevice.execute({
      id: request.file.filename,
      title,
      user_id: request.user.id,
      description,
      duration,
      post_time,
      tags,
    });

    return response.json(audio);
  },
);
```